# path error when using python read qt's ui file

Tags: python, pyside2

The UI file and the script is in the same dir, but when I use UI's name directly to load,it's shows error.When I use abs path to load it was successed.I need to pack it to exe file so I can's use abs path.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Not if you do not post the actual code. Currently we are expected to type all of it in. Make it easy to help you, not hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relative paths are with respect to where the script is executed, in your case from the image it can be said that your IDE launches it from "D:\Anaconda3\python.exe", so it is not recommended to use that type of paths but it is better to build the absolute path, in your case for example you can use the path of the .py file:

```py
CURRENT_DIRECTORY = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
filename = os.path.join(CURRENT_DIRECTORY, "uni.ui")
self.ui = QUiLoader().load(filename)
```